# Queue task for every user in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, queue, acid

The requirement is the user can take many actions at the same time (call API), but there some actions need to run sequentially for each user.

etc: user hit button **add item**, and **clear cart** the same time, but on the backend we need do it's sequentially, **done every phase** in action add item **before start any new phase** of action clear cart.
A phase can be called rest API to another service, query database or execute some javascripts code.

I am thinking about creating a queue job for every user's to archive this. Is that a good idea? What is the best way to do it, and are there any libraries for this (I have already searched but couldn't find anything)?

P/s: I'm using expressJS and MongoDB (> 4.0).

Edited:

If using a queue, how can i detect that user already has a queue or not to create a new one? If using Redis we can meet the race condition, or variable in ram can't help when I run nodejs as multi-cluster.

[image]

Comment: `I thinking about creating a queue job for every user` - go ahead - ask a question when you have an issue with code

Comment: @JaromandaX, I think this is a common problem so ask here you can get many good advice (about libraries or tutorial) because im new to nodejs. And i think that you accept create queue is 1 way acceptable to  archive this right? Thank you, i will working on this.

Comment: @JaromandaX i have an issue about race condition when create a user queue, updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

**bluebird** will solve this problem

code example:

```
action1()
   .then(phase1)
   .then(phase2)
   .then(phase3);

action2()
    .then(phase1)
    .then(phase2);
```

Comment: What is a bluebird? Give us a link

Comment: @Phu Le I think you talking about this, but it's don't make sure that action 2 will start after action 1 finish.
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html

Comment: action1()
   .then(phase1)
   .then(phase2)
   .then(phase3)
   .then(action2) // finish Action 1, run Action 2

You see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4sA99/60/)